# ImportError: No module named 'settings'

Tags: python, django

I have two versions of python installed 2.7 and 3.4 and created a virtualenv and assigned python34 to that new environment. When I activate that virtualenv and run `python manage.py runserver` then I get the following output.

```
(casenv) C:\pyprojects\focus\site>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\casenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\virtualenvs\casenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\virtualenvs\casenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\casenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\casenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\casenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 104, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\pyprojects\focus\site\general\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from focus2.util import HashedPk
  File "C:\pyprojects\focus\site\focus2\util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from settings import Hasher
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

File - manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "focus2.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The first 2 lines from utils.py --

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags, escape
from settings import Hasher
```

The project directory structure is

```
├───focus
│   ├───data_dumps
│   ├───notes
│   ├───setup
│   └───site(main project folder)
|       └───static
|       └───general
|       └───pro
|           └───models
|               +--__init__.py
|               +--plans.py
│       └───focus2
│           └───templates
|           +--__init__.py
│           +--settings.py
│           +--util.py            
│           +--wsgi.py
│       +--manage.py
```

I have the same code and dir structure which runs well with virtualenv python2.7. The difference between python27 env and python34 env is that I have installed mysql-python module in 27 and mysqlclient in 34.

Pip freeze command from python34 env.

```
(casenv) C:\virtualenvs\casenv>pip freeze
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.10.1
django-ajax-selects==1.5.0
django-allauth==0.32.0
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
easy-thumbnails==2.3
hashids==1.1.0
idna==2.5
lxml==3.7.3
mysqlclient==1.3.10
oauthlib==2.0.2
Pillow==3.3.1
PyMySQL==0.7.11
python3-openid==3.1.0
requests==2.18.3
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
urllib3==1.22
```

Pip freeze command from python27 virtualenv. I don't get any error while running this venv.

```
(testvenv27) C:\virtualenvs\testvenv27>pip freeze
Django==1.10.1
django-ajax-selects==1.5.0
django-allauth==0.27.0
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
easy-thumbnails==2.3
hashids==1.1.0
lxml==3.4.2
MySQL-python==1.2.5
oauthlib==2.0.0
Pillow==3.3.1
python-openid==2.2.5
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
```

The sys.path command output--

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\virtualenvs\\casenv\\DLLs', 'C:\\virtualenvs\\casenv\\lib', 'C:\\virtualenvs\\casenv\\Scripts', 'c:\\python34\\Lib', 'c:\\python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\virtualenvs\\casenv', 'C:\\virtualenvs\\casenv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
from .settings import Hasher
```

Comment: I tried and getting no module named django.conf.settings. for some reason it's not recognising DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE which is declared in manage.py

Comment: I have updated the post with output of sys.path and it seems fine.(looking for a wall to bang my head on)

Comment: @sasuke Bit improvement. I don't get setting module error but another module error. Which is coming from _init_.py under pro folder. In _init_.py the first line is - [ from plans import * ] and the runtime error is - no module named 'plans'. Both files _init_.py and plans.py are in same directory which is pro. I have updated my post directory structure.

Comment: try `from .plans import *`

Comment: It says    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra it is perfectly correct Python syntax. are you sure the error occurred in the `import` statement?

Comment: Ok so the import module error is gone. Now I am getting some syntax error which is related with python3. The code was originally developed in py2.7.

Comment: okay. If this answer helped you please mark the little tick so that it will be helpful for others with same problem.

Comment: With these kind of import problems it's not usually Django specific. My suggestion would be to make sure you're really confident on how imports work in Python, and particularly the way the Python path works. Often a good thing to do is to start up the Python console and try to run the same import statement and see if you can trigger the same error. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your directory and select setting in the directory  and open it with pycharm. When it open right click the tab and and click open in Terminal then run the code. It works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).